# How to add self-defined button to android custom keyboard?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, accessibilityservice

I want to develop a custom soft-keyboard for my android.
My problem is that I want to add 2 extra buttons which can acts whatever i want.
To be more precise, I want to have paste buttons for username and password on my keyboard so whenever I focus on a edit-box and push these buttons the corresponding task will be something like this:

```
 arguments.putCharSequence(AccessibilityNodeInfo
                    .ACTION_ARGUMENT_SET_TEXT_CHARSEQUENCE, "username");
            source.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_SET_TEXT, arguments);
```

or

```
 arguments.putCharSequence(AccessibilityNodeInfo
                    .ACTION_ARGUMENT_SET_TEXT_CHARSEQUENCE, "password");
            source.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_SET_TEXT, arguments);
```

Here is some part of my keyboard sample qwerty.xml:

```
 <Row>
    <Key android:codes="49" android:keyLabel="1" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
    <Key android:codes="50" android:keyLabel="2"/>
    <Key android:codes="51" android:keyLabel="3"/>
    <Key android:codes="52" android:keyLabel="4"/>
    <Key android:codes="53" android:keyLabel="5"/>
    <Key android:codes="54" android:keyLabel="6"/>
    <Key android:codes="55" android:keyLabel="7"/>
    <Key android:codes="56" android:keyLabel="8"/>
    <Key android:codes="57" android:keyLabel="9"/>
    <Key android:codes="48" android:keyLabel="0" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
</Row>
```

and here is the main code:

```
public class SimpleIME extends InputMethodService
    implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener {

private KeyboardView kv;
private Keyboard keyboard;

private boolean caps = false;

@Override
public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {

    InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
    playClick(primaryCode);
    switch(primaryCode){
        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE :
            ic.deleteSurroundingText(1, 0);
            break;
        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_SHIFT:
            caps = !caps;
            keyboard.setShifted(caps);
            kv.invalidateAllKeys();
            break;
        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DONE:
            ic.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER));
            break;
        default:
            char code = (char)primaryCode;
            if(Character.isLetter(code) && caps){
                code = Character.toUpperCase(code);
            }
            ic.commitText(String.valueOf(code),1);
    }

}

@Override
public void onPress(int primaryCode) {
}

@Override
public void onRelease(int primaryCode) {
}

@Override
public void onText(CharSequence text) {
}

@Override
public void swipeDown() {
}

@Override
public void swipeLeft() {
}

@Override
public void swipeRight() {
}

@Override
public void swipeUp() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateInputView() {
    kv = (KeyboardView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard, null);
    keyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.qwerty);
    kv.setKeyboard(keyboard);
    kv.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
    return kv;
}

private void playClick(int keyCode){
    AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
    switch(keyCode){
        case 32:
            am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_SPACEBAR);
            break;
        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DONE:
        case 10:
            am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_RETURN);
            break;
        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE:
            am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_DELETE);
            break;
        default: am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_STANDARD);
    }
}
```

I want to do something like [this](http://blog.agilebits.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/screenshot_2015-05-18-13-00-44.png)

Answer (score 0):

First off, you probably should not associate this problem with Accessibility Services.  This has nothing to do with accessibility services.  While this code may work as part of an accessibility service, it would be dependent on that service being on.  You want to stick within the realm of input service APIs.  What you really want to do is a batch edit.  This is the same type of code that a predictive keyboard would run, when a candidate is selected from a dictionary.  This code is thus:

```
 InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
 ic.beginBatchEdit();
 ic.commitText(text, cursorPositionAfterEdit);
 ic.endBatchEdit();
```

Comment: Actually what I really need to do is to add two buttons on my soft-keyboard and when I click on them I want to use accessibility service to paste whatever I want on my third party application editbox. (for example there is on free keycode like -101 that can b used but what an I assign for the second one)
The challenges that I faced is how can I defined a new KEYCODE which I need to initialized my buttons and the second challenge is when I clicked on these buttons I need to interact some how with accessibility and use those functions.

Comment: You can't do this.  Your accessibility service and your keyboard would completely separate processes.  You could hypothetically send intents back and forth, but there would be no way for you to guarantee that your service is running, while your keyboard is running.  Also, when you say "paste whatever you want" this also means that it had to have been copied from somewhere, and you couldn't know what has been copied recently, unless you're using your service to force the copy operation, which is a terrible practice.